# php MySQL INSERT value referencing another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

In the code below, I'm most concerned about the last three variables. The php variables (`$ae, $pe, and $de`) represent a user's full name as a string.

I'm trying to insert into `job_schedule` the user's ID that is from the table `users`.

Currently my result inserts all of the data into the table but places "0" into each record of the last three columns (AE, PE, DE) as if it was not able to find the `USERID`.

using PDO:

```
$res =  $db_qms->prepare("INSERT INTO `job_schedule` (`JID`, `HPL`, `WO`, `DESCRIP`, `MFG_LINE`, `CUSTOMER`, `AE`, `PE`, `DE`) VALUES (:jid, :hpl, :wo, :descrip, :mfg, :customer, :ae, :pe, :de)");
  $res->execute(array(
    ":jid" => $id,
    ":hpl" => $hpl,
    ":wo" => $wo,
    ":descrip" => $descrip,
    ":mfg" => $mfg,
    ":customer" => $customer,
    ":ae" => "SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE " . $ae . " LIKE (CONCAT(`users`.`FIRSTNAME`, ' ' , `users`.`LASTNAME`))",
    ":pe" => "SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE " . $pe . " LIKE (CONCAT(`users`.`FIRSTNAME`, ' ' , `users`.`LASTNAME`))",
    ":de" => "SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE " . $de . " LIKE (CONCAT(`users`.`FIRSTNAME`, ' ' , `users`.`LASTNAME`))"
  ));
```

I also tried to see if my SELECT statement was correct. So I ran the following code into phpMyAdmin SQL section and I was able to pull a value. So the Select statement works.

```
"SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE "John Doe" LIKE (CONCAT(`users`.`FIRSTNAME`, ' ' , `users`.`LASTNAME`))"
```

The result provided a value for `USERID`

I have no idea where to go from here. How do I insert the user's ID from `users.USERID` when I am given the user's full name?

Comment: Its seeming like I cannot do this in MySQL. I just made the entire statement into one huge statement and phpMyAdmin gave me errors. But if anyone knows how to get the user id given a full name (from another table) please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using INSERT SET syntax instead.

```
$rest = $db_qms->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO `job_schedule` " .
  "SET " .
    "`JID` = :jid, " .
    "`HPL` = :hpl, " .
    "`WO` = :wo, " .
    "`DESCRIP` = :descrip, " .
    "`MFG_LINE` = :mfg, "
    "`CUSTOMER` = :customer, " .
    "`AE` = (SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE (:ae LIKE CONCAT(`users`.`FIRSTNAME`, ' ', `users`.`LASTNAME`))), " .
    "`PE` = (SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE (:pe LIKE CONCAT(`users`.`FIRSTNAME`, ' ', `users`.`LASTNAME`))), " .
    "`DE` = (SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE (:de LIKE CONCAT(`users`.`FIRSTNAME`, ' ', `users`.`LASTNAME`)));"
);
$res->execute(array(
  ":jid" => $id,
  ":hpl" => $hpl,
  ":wo" => $wo,
  ":descrip" => $descrip,
  ":mfg" => $mfg,
  ":customer" => $customer,
  ":ae" => $ae,
  ":pe" => $pe,
  ":de" => $de
));
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried single quotes too and still nothing.

Comment: @Sanya I completely revised the answer because I realized that you were trying to post SQL as the value to a parameter. See if this revision works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen an sql statement use a string in the where clause as you are doing.

I would write the sql differently:

":ae" => "SELECT `USERID` FROM `users` WHERE CONCAT(users.FIRSTNAME, ' ', users.LASTNAME) LIKE \"" . $ae . "\"";

Comment: Still nothing. Is there a different way you would pull a user id given the user name?

Comment: An equality check will probably be sufficient either way.